# Submitting an image to Flask via curl fails with "not enough image data'

Tags: python, curl, flask, png, python-imaging-library

I am running a Flask webapp which accepts `POST` requests on the `/predict` path. The application, when called, executes the following code to transform the message bytes back into a PNG image:

```
from flask import request
from PIL import Image
img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (512,512), request.data, 'raw')
```

I'm submitting a valid 512-by-512 PNG image to this API via the following `curl` command:

```
curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict\
    -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"\
    --data-binary "@/Users/alex/Desktop/test_image_512.png"
```

The request is consistently failing with the following data:

```
  [...]
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/bob-ross-neural-painter/app/app.py", line 24, in predict
    Image.frombytes('RGBA', (512,512), request.data, 'raw')
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/spell-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2542, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/spell-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 829, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

I've verified that the PNG image ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuEaz.png)) is a valid 512x512 PNG image locally: `np.array(Image.open('/Users/alex/Desktop/test_image_512.png')).shape` returns `(512, 512, 4)`.

I can't seem to determine the root cause of the problem. Is the image being corrupted in transit somehow?

For reference, here's the full route definition:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # bytes -> PIL image -> array -> tensor
    img = torch.tensor(
        np.array(
            Image.frombytes('RGBA', (512,512), request.data, 'raw')
        )
    )
```

Comment: See [pillow#4337](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4337).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pillow` `Image.fromarray` method expects a raw bytemap as input, and will not work when given encoded pixel bytes like e.g. the PNG-encoded pixels in this example. The correct way to handle this case is to use `BytesIO` and `Image.open` instead:

```py
with open('test_image_512.png', 'rb') as f:
    img_b = f.read()
Image.open(BytesIO(img_b))
```